# BlackBerry: WhatsApp messageStore.db file decryption

Tags: python, blackberry, whatsapp

For Android and iPhone I am able to decrypt my WhatsApp encrypted message file using python. But for BlackBerry I haven't had any success.

Comment: Check this answer for decrypting the [whatsApp crypt5 DB(android code).](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23380177/2219600)

Comment: No idea how to make the above code work. All i know is:
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1583021
says that Blackberry is not supported yet.

Answer (score 2):

Searching for "whatsapp database encryption" (on Bing no less) turns up this student report out of the Netherlands:
[WhatsApp Database Encryption Project Report](https://www.os3.nl/_media/2011-2012/students/ssn_project_report.pdf)

There's a section on BlackBerry specifically, that says:

> The header tells us that we are dealing with a file that took
>   advantage of the encryption possibilities of the BlackBerry encryption
>   system.