# WhatsApp: how to decode the *.db.crypt files?

Tags: php, python, mobile, encoding, whatsapp

I'd like to read *.db.crypt-files, preferably with PHP. The content is encoded.

Does anyone know how to decode the content or how to figure out what kind of encoding was used?

It's possible. The tool "WhatsApp Xtract" is able to do it, but it's written in python.

Comment: I would go for the python tool and examine it's source-code to find out about which encoding is used.

After you've found out, you can port it to PHP.

Comment: @hakre Thanks for your reply! I'll examine the python code.

Comment: Check this answer for decrypting the [whatsApp crypt5 DB(android code).](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23380177/2219600)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$crypt = file_get_contents('msgstore.db.crypt');
$key = pack('H*', '346a23652a46392b4d73257c67317e352e3372482177652c');
$decrypt = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $crypt, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
```

Comment: Great, thx! But how to get the `$enc`? Do you mean `$crypt`, maybe?

Comment: The decrypted data is still encrypted. Is `346................52c` the right key/hash?

Comment: @Mr.Bombastic Yes, sorry, $enc was $crypt, I have updated the code with the correct key too.

Comment: That works fine, thx! There are still crypted lines. I will check if these lines are sent/received images. Another point are Emoticons. A lot of strange lines but the messages are in plain text and readable. Answer happy accepted! :-)