# How to get number of unread messages from whatsapp

Tags: android, whatsapp

I can get the number of unread messages like this:

```
final Uri SMS_INBOX = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");

Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(SMS_INBOX, null, "read = 0", null, null);
int unreadMessagesCount = c.getCount();
c.deactivate();
```

Is there any similar way to get the number of unread messages from whatsapp?

I have searched google and took a glance at the whatsapp api but did not find anything usefull.

Comment: did Whatsapp released an sdk?

Comment: possible duplicate of [reading whatsapp messages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15494757/reading-whatsapp-messages)

Comment: @Paresh Mayani: No, this is no duplicate. I just want the unread message counter to display on a widget. I don't want to read any messages etc.

Comment: @user1567896 then WhatsApp must have developed **content provider** for such functionality.