# how does Whatsapp save the chats immediately, NOT the backups

Tags: android, whatsapp

My Question is about the way Whatsapp saves the conversation in the time we chat, so , if I close whatsapp, and open it, my last conversations and messages that not yet backed up appear...  even if I send a letter (one character), and close the application and the open it, I will find this letter!!
Where does whatsapp saves these conversations. and restore them...

We don't talk about the DB backups.

Comment: You might find this useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/saving-activity-state-in-android

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whats app stores the conversation in the database, that is in the phonememory(Only rooted phones can access that).

Here is the structure of the latest whats app Database:

- messages
- sqlite_sequence
- chat_list
  [image]

However, it takes a backup at 4am everyday and saves it as a db.crypt# file in the sd card. There are ways to access that though, here is one : https://stackoverflow.com/a/23380177/2219600

Answer (score 1):

they maybe using [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html), and after a certain file size is reached, they might replace the preference.