# how to Read /Write all Whatsapp Messages in backup file using Python or JAVA

Tags: java, python, database, whatsapp

I want to read all the WhatsApp messages from the backup taken from the Windows phone and write those messages in a document or in the iPhone.

I have read many questions, that were limited to crypt5 only as the WhatsApp has changed a lot. Following the order of my backup file.
[image]

How to **read and write** the WhatsApp messages from this backup file.

Comment: Have you read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8856874/get-all-messages-from-whatsapp?

Answer (score 0):

Your system detects file extension of "messages" as "Data Base File",
you have to get exact messages file extension, and open that database with corresponding tool.

Comment: do you know any tool to perform such action?

Comment: do you got exact file extension?