# Import whatsapp chat in a app

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, whatsapp

I would like to import whatsapp chats in my app; I try to use content provider but response is permission denied; This is my first app and this is the first time that I use content provider so I don't know if it is impossible to import chat or something in my code is wrong.

My code is:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://com.whatsapp.fileprovider");

ContentProviderClient cr = getContentResolver().acquireContentProviderClient(uri);
```

Comment: are you using android m or above?? if yes then you have to check the permissions on run time

Comment: I'm using JELLY_BEAN

Comment: then you should not face any permission problems if and only if whatsapp shares its chats through its api

Comment: Please confirm that whatsapp provides this feature

Comment: please check these answers here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8856874/get-all-messages-from-whatsapp