# Why I'm getting java.security.InvalidKey Exception?

Tags: java, aes, whatsapp

I'm trying decrypt whatup db file (which I copied to my PC, and run from my PC, under linux).

The initialize vector and key are:

```
private byte[] key = { (byte) 141, 75, 21, 92, (byte) 201, (byte) 255,
        (byte) 129, (byte) 229, (byte) 203, (byte) 246, (byte) 250, 120,
        25, 54, 106, 62, (byte) 198, 33, (byte) 166, 86, 65, 108,
        (byte) 215, (byte) 147 };


private final byte[] iv = { 0x1E, 0x39, (byte) 0xF3, 0x69, (byte) 0xE9, 0xD,
        (byte) 0xB3, 0x3A, (byte) 0xA7, 0x3B, 0x44, 0x2B, (byte) 0xBB,
        (byte) 0xB6, (byte) 0xB0, (byte) 0xB9 };
```

And when I'm running this code:

```
  Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
  SecretKeySpec secret = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
  IvParameterSpec vector = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
  cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secret, vector);
```

I'm getting exception on the init function:
"`java.security.InvalidKeyException: Illegal key size`"

I used this post:

[Get all messages from Whatsapp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8856874/get-all-messages-from-whatsapp)

What is wrong ?

Comment: Google InvalidKeyException Illegal Key Size and the first three hits all answer your question. (24 bytes is 192 bits and 192 is more than 128, which is the limit for Oracle/Sun Java before 9 or 8u151.)

Comment: so what is the right key ? (in order to decrypt whatup DB) ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess The JDK key size which does not allow you to encrypt with key whose size is more than 128 bits.

Comment: So how can I use JDK to decrypt whatsup DB ?

Comment: Maybe you can change the core settings of JDK by manipulating oracle java setting files ,policies etc.